# Bootstrap 4 load popup iframe after click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Currently i have 100 iframe on my website which gets loaded directly after visiting index page.

Please find my code bellow:

```
cell.innerHTML+=  "<a title='Attachemnts' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#"+id+"' class='btn btn-xs btn-default'><span class='fa fa-paperclip'></span></a>&nbsp;"
cell.innerHTML+=  "<div id='"+id+"' class='modal fade' role='dialog'><div class='modal-dialog'><!-- Modal content--><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button><h4 class='modal-title'><iframe src='attachments.php"+id+"'></iframe></h4></div><div class='modal-body'><p>test</p></div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button></div></div></div></div>";
```

for better visual pasting only html content of same code

```html
 <a title='Attachemnts' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#"+id+"' class='btn btn-xs btn-default'><span class='fa fa-paperclip'>
    
    <div id='"+id+"' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
    <div class='modal-dialog'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
    <h4 class='modal-title'><iframe src='attachments.php"+id+"'></iframe></h4></div>
    <div class='modal-body'><p>test</p></div><div class='modal-footer'>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button></div></div></div></div>
```

What i want to do is load content of each iframe individual only after clicking bootstrap modal button.

I googled more than 40 pages and was not able to find the solution hopefully somebody can help me on this topic

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly i have build a solution:

Javascript

```
$('a.video').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('attachmentid');
    var src = 'attachment.php?ref='+id;
    $("#attachment").attr('src', src);
    $('#test').modal('show');
    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<a attachmentid='GS0089' class='video btn btn-xs btn-default'>Popup</a>
<div id='test' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
<div class='modal-dialog'>
<div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'>
<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
<h4 class='modal-title'>Modal Header "+id+"</h4></div>
<div class='modal-body'><div class='video-wrapper'>
    <iframe id='attachment' width='560' height='315' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div></div>
<div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button></div></div></div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/George_Skyway/j4we7zhh/4/